# How to pass constructor arguments to ninjectcontrollerfactory in asp.net mvc DI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject.web.mvc

I am working on asp.net mvc 4. I am trying to implement dependeny injection using ninject and repository pattern with code first model.

**IMessageRepository**

```
public interface IMessageRepository
{
void IsMessageRead();
}
```

**MessageRepository**

```
 public class MessageRepository:IMessageRepository
 {
 string id="";
 public MessageRepository(string idparam)
 {
   id=idparam;
 }
 EFMsgContext context=new EFMsgContext(id);
 public void IsMessageRead()
 {
  ...
 }
 }
```

**EFMsgContext**

```
public class EFMsgContext:Dbcontext
{
public EFMsgContext(string id):base("MyContext")
{
 //based on id i will construct a connection string from my database.
}
....
}
```

**my controller**

```
public class MYController:Controller
{
private IMessageRepository repo;
public MYController(IMessageRepository repoparam)
{
repo=repoparam;
}
public ActionResult Index()
{
  repo.IsMessageRead();
}
}
```

and i am using Ninject for dependency injection i bind my interface with concrete class like,

```
ninjectKernel.Bind<IMessageRepository>().To<MessageRepository>();
```

here how could i pass constructor parameters to the binding and  is there any way to write the logic for buidling connection string inside the ninjectcontrollerfactory. please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `WithConstructorArgument` extension method

```
ninjectKernel.Bind<IMessageRepository>().To<MessageRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("idparam", value);
```

You can even pass a `Func` as a second argument.

```
ninjectKernel.Bind<IMessageRepository>().To<MessageRepository>()
             .WithConstructorArgument("idparam", (c) => {
                   // read from somewhere and return
              });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. `value` variable is predefined or we initialize it manually.

Comment: If my MessageRepository class have two constructors (with parameter and with out parameter) then i need to register twice in ninject? thanks in advance